# Closure: Standard clef arrangement for SATB

Tags: support, close-reasons

[Standard clef arrangement for SATB](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/standard-clef-arrangement-for-satb)

---

My question here was closed as off-topic.  Can someone explain to me why this was closed?

---

If this is on-topic on **Music SE**, I would love to ask it there, but my account is suspended and I could not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got both a comment and a standard close reason indicating why. This SE does not have the same scope as Music SE so asking more involved questions about the history of notation does not make sense here.

Comment: Dom, then what can I do in order to post it without it being closed as off-topic?  I need a response to this as soon as possible.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya You could start by taking a look at the [help/on-topic] and compare it to Music.SE's [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). After that, take the list that explicitly tells what not to ask ([Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). Questions that are not within scope, will be closed. It works like that on every SE site. If you don't want your question to get closed, ask a question that's within the scope of the site.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya If music.SE is the place to ask your question, that's the place to ask it. Not here. If you're suspended there, well, that's a completely different problem and you may want to fix that first.

Comment: But a **1-year suspension is applied to my Music SE account** which is currently still in effect, and I could not ask there (while I am desperate).  I apparently still need to wait for another 9 months as they aren't really willing to lift my suspension early.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya To get a 1-year suspension, you must have done something to really piss them off. Take those 9 months to reflect on what it was and don't do it again. Decisions, actions, consequences. That's not a valid reason to start posting it here instead.

Comment: @Mast - well... the recommended durations are 7 days, 30 days, and a year for the first, second, and third suspensions.  I got a 7 on Jan, 30 on Apr, and a year on Aug.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya I'd seriously caution you not to get suspended again then, or it's going to be a long wait. Please take this as a learning opportunity.

Comment: @Yes... they say that for the **4th** suspension (after the 365) is [usually 3 or 5 years, or another 365 if I am lucky enough.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337396/how-do-moderators-decide-how-long-to-suspend-users-for#comment1121361_337399)

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya this is your final warning please stop bringing up your suspension  on music SE here and using it to try and justify actions.  1. The music SE suspension will not be lifted early. 2. The suspension does not change what is on and off topic on this se. 3. Constantly bringing it up here does nothing but disrupt this community since it has nothing to do with the suspension and can't affect it.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya, you need to understand that we are not Music SE. We deal with different topics and have rules. You seem to want to always bend rules to achieve your personal agenda and disrespect our community and users for something we didn't do. I was first really happy, [when you introduced yourself](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/some-tips-for-good-contribution), to see a potential active member and thought that one-year suspension could be unfair... but now I understand: you didn't actually want to help the community but only yourself.

Comment: @Bebs - No, I also really wanted to help the community as well.  That's why I've been running through the review queues every night lately before I went to bed.  But I also need to hear the mods' opinions about deleting my account.

Comment: I agree you helped, but you also complained a lot even if we said there is nothing we could do since it's a different community. You keep asking questions about theory even if we said it's off-topic. You'll be welcome if you want to stay, but please read the rules and the scope.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya The mods' opinions on your account deletion are *irrelevant*, since they won't change anything about either your suspension on another site or your questions on this site. If you want to delete your account, that is *your* decision, but don't use that to hold this or any other site hostage with a moral theat of "you made me delete my account". This is not going to happen. Noone wants you to delete your account. Either contribute constructively or leave it be.

Comment: @Maika_Sakuran0miya **You were suspended. You lost the privilege of asking those questions.** The time to do something to ask that question has long since passed. You've been around for long enough on SE that *you should know  what to do if your question isn't on-topic*; after all, **you've been suspended on at least three different SE sites, including this one.**

Comment: @Maika_Sakuran0miya I don't think any of us want you to leave the site. We need every active user we can get. A lot of your contributions have been good and useful. Some have been off topic. All we are asking is that you 1. learn which topics to avoid (i.e. those that belong on Music SE) and 2. stop reminding us about your ban on Music SE.